# codeigniter how to upload picture to folder, web/assets/picture/

Tags: php, image, file, codeigniter, upload

I am using codeigniter and I want to upload a file picture to my folder,
path is `web/assets/picture/`.

I've looked here and cannot fix it with the answer I found. Please help.

This my view where to input the picture :

```
echo form_open_multipart("adminFolder/admin/insert_picture");   
echo form_upload("userfile", "Gambar Picture"); 
echo form_submit("input_picture", "Input now !!!");
```

My controller the insert_picture :

```
        if($this->input->post("userfile")){
            $this->model_get->doUpload();

            $this->adminPic();
        }else{
            $this->insertPicture();
        }
```

My model :

```
function doUpload(){

        $config['upload_path'] = '../assets/images/'; 
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg'; 
        $config['max_size'] = '2048'; 
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768'; 
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;

        $this->load->library("upload", $config);
        $this->upload->do_upload(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your upload_path to:

```
$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'web/assets/picture/';
```

The `FCPATH` constant returns the path to your main directory.

Make sure the directory exists and it writeable.

Comment: how do i check permission on directory ??
and how do i change it ??